# Autoit - Get Window Class by PID

Tags: class, autoit, pid

I want Autoit to press a certain key on a program, but the programs window has no title and changes its class everytime I start it. The only thing that stays consistently the same is the process name.

So my question is simply: How do I get a Windows Class by using only the PID?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>

Opt("WinDetectHiddenText", 1) ;0=don't detect, 1=do detect
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
Opt("WinTextMatchMode", 2) ;1=complete, 2=quick
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase


$a = ProcessGetId('firefox.exe')

For $i = 1 To UBound($a) - 1
    ConsoleWrite(ProcessGetWindow($a[$i]) & @CRLF)
Next

Func ProcessGetWindow($PId)
    If IsNumber($PId) = 0 Or ProcessExists(ProcessGetName($PId)) = 0 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $WinList = WinList()
        Local $i = 1
        Local $WindowTitle = ""
        While $i <= $WinList[0][0] And $WindowTitle = ""
            If WinGetProcess($WinList[$i][0], "") = $PId Then
                $WindowTitle = $WinList[$i][0]
            Else
                $i += 1
            EndIf
        WEnd
        Return $WindowTitle
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetWindow

Func ProcessGetId($Process)
    If IsString($Process) = 0 Then
        SetError(2)
    ElseIf ProcessExists($Process) = 0 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $PList = ProcessList($Process)
        Local $i
        Local $PId[$PList[0][0] + 1]
        $PId[0] = $PList[0][0]
        For $i = 1 To $PList[0][0]
            $PId[$i] = $PList[$i][1]
        Next
        Return $PId
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetId

Func ProcessGetName($PId)
    If IsNumber($PId) = 0 Then
        SetError(2)
    ElseIf $PId > 9999 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $PList = ProcessList()
        Local $i = 1
        Local $ProcessName = ""

        While $i <= $PList[0][0] And $ProcessName = ""
            If $PList[$i][1] = $PId Then
                $ProcessName = $PList[$i][0]
            Else
                $i = $i + 1
            EndIf
        WEnd
        Return $ProcessName
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetName
```